# Does anyone face the Workbench entrance error?

Tags: login, workbench

The entrance issue is when I login to Workbench using "Login with Salesforce" button and nothing is happened.
There is nothing appaeared and I see the login window again.
Approx. 1 hour and still could not login into the Workbench.

Comment: are you using mydomain and logging in with the Custom domain option?

Comment: no, i don't use custom domain. I used my Salesforce cretencials as usual.

Comment: This is same with everyone,  workbench is not officially supported by salesforce you would need to wait until we have fix, see if you can deploy it to [heroku](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench) and use.

Comment: Same here, unfortunately...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/405728/unknown-error-read-error-on-connection-to-ec2-34-194-152-137-compute-1-amazonaw)