# Workbench: read error on connection to ...amazonaws.com when executing SOQL in interactive mode

Tags: workbench

I was happily using Workbench as usual then after dinner I started receiving error message "UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379" for any Query. I tried different api versions and different browsers to not avail. Anyone having this error?

Edit: It works properly if you choose to use Bulk CSV or Bulk XML and download file to see results.

Comment: This has been reported by multiple customers. I'll let you know as I have an update on this . Also see https://workbench.developerforce.com/help.php   Thanks

Comment: Welcome to users finding this question via search. **Please do not post "I'm having the same problem" in answers or comments**. If you have a solution to share, please check out [answer]. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a Salesforce "known issue" for this?

Comment: I did report it to Salesforce, but they said it's not their product.

Comment: Workbench is working fine for me, so it looks like it is a problem with your end. Have you tried using an incognito browser window to access it? If that works, try clearing all cookies for workbench.developerforce.com and login again. If it doesn't work, have you tried logging in with different credentials? If that doesn't work, have you tried using a different browser? If that doesn't work, have you tried accessing over a different network (e.g. tether from your phone)?

Comment: BTW, I guess it depends what you're trying to do, but I find workbench to be clunky (like the dev console). There are better tools that are more focused on specific tasks - use an IDE (such as VSCode) and sfdx for development, use sfdx to run anon apex scripts, use postman for API testing, use the Salesforce Inspector chrome extension to get additional detail from records etc.

Comment: You should [edit] to add details. Still, did you try the various options listed above?

Comment: BTW Workbench is easy to use for a non developer Admin.  Developers can hand  the admin an anonymous script that they can run without having to deal with any of the developer tools installed on their device.

Comment: Sure, the tool still has its place. Just saying there are other options as well that are fit for purpose, depending on your purpose.

Comment: So, on the main problem, can you actually login to the org itself with the same credentials?

Comment: I find Salesforce Inspector as easy to use if not more easy than Workbench for doing queries.

Comment: yes i can log into the org. Also I tried with 2 production accounts and 2 sandbox accounts all giving the same results

Comment: thanks @fred i actually did not pay attention to that part of salesforce inspector chrome extension. So that solves my SOQL issue

Comment: Agree with portions of Workbench being down. - I can successfully use info on standard and custom objects. - I can run Rest commands against describe of an object, or specific objects and get data back. So I know that the org is connected and i have permissions to the data. - I am UNABLE to run SOQL commands, getting the same error as published above. This is a simple `Select Id from Account`, all the way to complicated SOQLs that i first attempted. So most of it is working with a problem of pulling multiple records through SOQL viewed as a list. An incognito Screen does NOT help. SOQL DOES wo

Comment: Salesforce Inspector does not work for me. I click on the extension icon and it goes back to the chrome web store.

Comment: With a bit of cautious optimism, there has been a report of someone else saying queries using workbench.developerforce.com are working again. I've tried it out myself just now, and the "List" option for "view as" works for me.

Answer (score 2):

26/06/2023 This solution did not work for me when I faced these issues again. So it may or may not work for you.

22/06/2023 I was facing a similar issue, I was able to resolve this issue by going to my User Settings and Revoking Workbench OAuth Apps setting.
Attaching a screenshot here -- >
[image]

28/06/2023 As a workaround you can use Bulk CSV options. I hope this helps
[image]
[image]

Comment: This did not work for me and continue to experience the same error.

Answer (score 2):

For doing SOQL queries an alternative tool to use is [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh) (a Chrome extension). It is very easy to use.

Comment: Salesforce Inspector does not work for me. I click on the extension icon and it goes back to the chrome web store.

Comment: To use it there is a little arrow that appears on the right whenever you're on a Salesforce page.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the closed pull requests on the project's Github](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed), the issue appears to be fixed now. Using the "List" option for "View As" appears to be working in my limited, independent testing (tested using API v57.0 and v58.0).

workbench.developerforce.com is hosted on Heroku (the "developerforce" instance from here on), which in turn uses Amazon's AWS (hence "amazonaws" appearing in the error message).

According to the pull requests, the issue was related to Redis v6 (developerforce appears to use a Heroku add-on, "Heroku Data for Redis", as a session store for operation across multiple compute resources, or "Dynos" in Heroku parlance) and making a TLS connection.

Heroku started requiring TLS for connections to its Redis add-on for all but the "mini" instance (where TLS is supposedly only suggested rather than required) when using Heroku Data for Redis v6. URLs and port numbers may have changed, and this add-on uses a self-signed cert (which required some additional changes in setting up the TLS connection from PHP, namely disabling peer verification).

There was also apparently some work that needed to be done because the session save handler (in the Redis driver that PHP provides?) isn't able to handle TLS connections yet.

Shoutout to Ryan Brainard for putting in the work on this.

Comment: Workbench is working for me! Thank you Ryan for solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with Workbench connection to a specific org where you can successfully login to that org directly, you might want to ask your admin (if you don't have permissions) to go to Setup > Apps > Connected Apps > Connected Apps OAuth Usage:

[image: Connected App OAuth Usage]

Click the "User Count" link against Workbench, find your username and hit the "Revoke" action.

This will then require you to re-authenticate against Workbench with your credentials, potentially fixing your problem.

Comment: Tried this and it did not work

Comment: Fair enough, though it can help when problems arise so I'll leave it here for other solution seekers. So, if it's not the browser, the network, the credentials or credential-related state, that makes it sound like you've hit an issue in your org itself. Are you able to perform the equivalent of what you are doing through Workbench using the developer console, with the same credentials?