# When at the login screen, after I enter my credentials the page refreshes back to the login screen

Tags: workbench, login-errors, sforce.connection

When at the login screen, after I enter my credentials the page refreshes back to the login screen. I have tried clearing cache and hard reload, but it still doesn't let me in. can anyone help here? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/405728/unknown-error-read-error-on-connection-to-ec2-34-194-152-137-compute-1-amazonaw)